# Calculating max/min value in a loop

Tags: python, loops

I'm very new to programming and have recently started a class on Python programming. The problem is the Gambler's ruin where you start with $3 and flip a coin to either gain a dollar or lose a dollar depending on if it's heads or tails. I'm then running it 100 times and need to calculate the max and min number of coin flips to get to $0. I'm having trouble figuring out the max and min function for this. There is probably a rather basic solution but can anyone help?

Here is what I have so far:

```py
# while loop, let's assume '1' = heads and '2' = tails, b = balance and c = count


b = 3
c = 0
while (b > 0):
    flipResult = random.randint(1,2)
    if (flipResult == 1):
            b += 1
    if (flipResult == 2):
            b -= 1
    c += 1        
    print('Your balance is...')
    print(b)
print('Total flip count is...')
print(c)



# wrapping in a loop to repeat simulation 100 times


for trialNumber in range(100):
    b = 3
    c = 0
    while (b > 0):
        flipResult = random.randint(1,2)
        if (flipResult == 1):
                b += 1
        if (flipResult == 2):
                b -= 1
        c += 1        
        print('Your balance is...')
        print(b)
    print('Total flip count is...')
    print(c)
```

Comment: What happens if the amount of money on hand never drops to 0?

Comment: Apparently, the balance will always go down to $0 if the gambler continues to play. I was surprised by this but I ran it many times.

Comment: It is *expected* to always go down to 0, but for any `C > 0`, there is always a chance that you'll need more than `C` flips for that to happen.

Comment: I removed the `random` tag since how to generate random numbers doesn't affect the answer you're seeking. If you read values from a file rather than generating them randomly, the solution for finding the min/max would not change in any way.

Answer (score 1):

You can create 2 new variables outside the loop, and update them with the max and min values:

```py
import random

maxFlips = -float('inf')
minFlips = float('inf')

for trialNumber in range(100):
    b = 3
    c = 0
    while (b > 0):
        flipResult = random.randint(1,2)
        if (flipResult == 1):
                b += 1
        if (flipResult == 2):
                b -= 1
        c += 1        
        print('Your balance is...')
        print(b)
    print('Total flip count is...')
    print(c)
    
    maxFlips = max(maxFlips,c)
    minFlips = min(minFlips,c)

print('Max Flips:', maxFlips)
print('Min Flips:', minFlips)
```

Every trial, the max/min number of flips are updated if they are less than the current max/min.
The max/min are printed at the end

Comment: You could reduce your 5 lines for the flip logic to just `b += random.choice([-1,1])`.

Answer (score 0):

Updated:

```
def simulate_coin_flip_game():
    b = 3
    c = 0
    while b > 0:
        flip_result = random.randint(1, 2)
        if flip_result == 1:
            b += 1
        elif flip_result == 2:
            b -= 1
        c += 1
        print('Your balance is:', b)

    print('Total flip count is:', c)
    return c

results = []
for trial_number in range(100):
    flip_count = simulate_coin_flip_game()
    results.append(flip_count)

average_flips = sum(results) / len(results)
min_flips = min(results)
max_flips = max(results)

print('Average flip count over 100 trials:', average_flips)
print('Minimum flip count over 100 trials:', min_flips)
print('Maximum flip count over 100 trials:', max_flips)
```

Comment: This doesn't calculate the minimum or maximum value of `c`.

Comment: @slothrop, Updated answer, please check and suggest if anything missing. Thanks in advance

Answer (score -2):

if you are making a simulation I would make a list for the results and add them in each trial I would append this results in the list. Finally I would use min() or max() functions to find these values. In addition to this, you should consider that np.random.randint(low_value,high_value) function includes a range of integers between [low_value,high_value) that includes the low_value but excludes the high_value. This is why your code is always showing a 1 resultf for this function. For example if you run np.random.randint(1,5) you can have outputs of:1,2,3 or 4 (5 is not included in this list) .

I recomend the following corrections:

```
import numpy as np
flip_count_results=[]
for trialNumber in range(100):
    balance = 3
    count = 0
    while (balance > 0):
        flipresult = np.random.randint(0,2)
        if (flipresult == 0):
                balance += 1
        if (flipresult == 1):
                balance -= 1
        count += 1
    flip_count_results.append(count)
print(flip_count_results)
print('The max number of flip counts is '+ str(max(flip_count_results)))
print('The min number of flip counts is '+ str(min(flip_count_results)))
```

Comment: `np.random.randint` does exclude the high_value, but `random.randint` (which OP used) does not. So `np.random.randint(0,2)` and `random.randint(1,2)` both choose from 2 numbers with 50% probability each. https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint

Comment: Thx for the info. I didn't knew